# Extract data from list with some conditions

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, machine-learning, extract

Basically, I am trying to adding two midi files and there is not much information on internet about it, so I am trying my own.

What I did so far is I have added two midi's messages (type of midi's data)
and I have list of both midi messages. This means I have all the data in which I need to merge two midi now. The problem is that I can't add data in a particular format.

So my code is :

```
  from mido import MidiFile, MidiTrack

mid = MidiFile('har.mid')
mid2 = MidiFile('har2.mid')

l = [msg for track in mid.tracks for msg in track]
l.pop()
ka = [msg for track in mid2.tracks for msg in track]
ka.pop()

result = l + ka

for messagess in result:
    print(messagess)
```

I am getting this output :

```
note_on channel=0 note=59 velocity=40 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=60 velocity=40 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=64 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=59 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=64 velocity=0 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=52 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=60 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=64 velocity=40 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=67 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=67 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=57 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=52 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=57 velocity=0 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=64 velocity=0 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=57 velocity=40 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=57 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=64 velocity=40 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=67 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=64 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=67 velocity=0 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=57 velocity=40 time=110
note_on channel=0 note=64 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=57 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=64 velocity=0 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=57 velocity=40 time=110
note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=57 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=0 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=60 velocity=40 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=40 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=67 velocity=40 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=60 velocity=40 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=64 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=60 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=0 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=64 velocity=0 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=67 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=64 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=64 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=60 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=60 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=64 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=64 velocity=0 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=60 velocity=40 time=110
note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=60 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=0 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=48 velocity=40 time=110
note_on channel=0 note=62 velocity=40 time=0
note_off channel=0 note=48 velocity=0 time=55
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=0 time=0
note_on channel=0 note=57 velocity=40 time=55
note_on channel=0 note=60 velocity=40 time=0
```

Now this is ok but the problem is i can add messages to track in [this format :](http://mido.readthedocs.io/en/latest/midi_files.html#creating-a-new-file)

```
from mido import Message, MidiFile, MidiTrack

mid = MidiFile()
track = MidiTrack()
mid.tracks.append(track)

track.append(Message('program_change', program=12, time=0))
track.append(Message('note_on', note=64, velocity=64, time=32))
track.append(Message('note_off', note=64, velocity=127, time=32))

mid.save('new_song.mid')
```

so my question how append each line from this format :

```
note_off channel=0 note=62 velocity=0 time=0
```

to this format

`'note_off', note=62, velocity=0, time=0`

in  `track.append(Message())`

because track.append support only this format method :

```
track.append(Message('note_off', note=62, velocity=0, time=0))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type() of messages? A string?

Comment: They are not string but we can convert them using repr() i think

Comment: What does this question have to do with machine learning tag?

Answer (score 2):

```
from mido import MidiFile, MidiTrack

mid = MidiFile('har.mid')
mid2 = MidiFile('har2.mid')

l = [msg for track in mid.tracks for msg in track]
l.pop()
ka = [msg for track in mid2.tracks for msg in track]
ka.pop()

result = l + ka

mid3 = MidiFile()
track = MidiTrack()
mid3.tracks.append(track)

for m in result:
    track.append(m)

mid3.save('new_song.mid')
```

The objects in `result` should already be `Message` objects, so you should't need to construct them again.  Try this code, and if it doesn't work please copy the full error message you get back.